# Python Pandas: What is the fastest way to create a datetime index?

Tags: python, performance, parsing, datetime, pandas

My data looks like so:

```
TEST
2012-05-01 00:00:00.203 OFF 0
2012-05-01 00:00:11.203 OFF 0
2012-05-01 00:00:22.203 ON 1
2012-05-01 00:00:33.203 ON 1
2012-05-01 00:00:44.203 OFF 0
TEST
2012-05-02 00:00:00.203 OFF 0
2012-05-02 00:00:11.203 OFF 0
2012-05-02 00:00:22.203 OFF 0
2012-05-02 00:00:33.203 ON 1
2012-05-02 00:00:44.203 ON 1
2012-05-02 00:00:55.203 OFF 0
```

I'm using `pandas` `read_table` to read a pre-parsed string (which gets rid of the "TEST" lines) like so:

```
df = pandas.read_table(buf, sep=' ', header=None, parse_dates=[[0, 1]], date_parser=dateParser, index_col=[0])
```

So far, i've tried several date parsers, the uncommented one being the fastest.

```
def dateParser(s):
#return datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
return datetime(int(s[0:4]), int(s[5:7]), int(s[8:10]), int(s[11:13]), int(s[14:16]), int(s[17:19]), int(s[20:23])*1000)
#return np.datetime64(s)
#return pandas.Timestamp(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", tz='utc' )
```

Is there anything else I can do to speed things up? I need to read large amounts of data - several Gb per file.

Comment: Do you have an say on the format your data comes in? That is, could you have a tab-delimited file where the date and time fields are space separated?

Comment: @diliop: No, I cannot influence the input data format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick answer is that **what you indicate as the fastest way to parse your date/time strings into a `datetime`-type index, is indeed the fastest way**. I timed some of your approaches and some others and this is what I get.

First,getting an example `DataFrame` to work with:

```
import datetime
from pandas import *

start = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2012, 12, 1)
d = DateRange(start, end, offset=datetools.Hour())
t_df = DataFrame({'field_1': np.array(['OFF', 'ON'])[np.random.random_integers(0, 1, d.size)], 'field_2': np.random.random_integers(0, 1, d.size)}, index=d)
```

Where:

```
In [1]: t_df.head()
Out[1]: 
                    field_1  field_2
2000-01-01 00:00:00      ON        1
2000-01-01 01:00:00     OFF        0
2000-01-01 02:00:00     OFF        1
2000-01-01 03:00:00     OFF        1
2000-01-01 04:00:00      ON        1
In [2]: t_df.shape
Out[2]: (113233, 2)
```

This is an approx. 3.2MB file if you dump it on disk. We now need to drop the `DataRange` type of your `Index` and make it a list of `str` to simulate how you would parse in your data:

```
t_df.index = t_df.index.map(str)
```

If you use `parse_dates = True` when reading your data into a `DataFrame` using `read_table` you are looking at **9.5sec** mean parse time:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np
In [4]: import timeit
In [5]: t_df.to_csv('data.tsv', sep='\t', index_label='date_time')
In [6]: t = timeit.Timer("from __main__ import read_table; read_table('data.tsv', sep='\t', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)")
In [7]: np.mean(t.repeat(10, number=1))
Out[7]: 9.5226533889770515
```

The other strategies rely on parsing your data into a `DataFrame` first (negligible parsing time) and then converting your index to an `Index` of `datetime` objects:

```
In [8]: t = timeit.Timer("from __main__ import t_df, dateutil; map(dateutil.parser.parse, t_df.index.values)")
In [9]: np.mean(t.repeat(10, number=1))
Out[9]: 7.6590064525604244
In [10]: t = timeit.Timer("from __main__ import t_df, dateutil; t_df.index.map(dateutil.parser.parse)")
In [11]: np.mean(t.repeat(10, number=1))
Out[11]: 7.8106775999069216
In [12]: t = timeit.Timer("from __main__ import t_df, datetime; t_df.index.map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"))")
Out[12]: 2.0389052629470825
In [13]: t = timeit.Timer("from __main__ import t_df, np; map(np.datetime_, t_df.index.values)")
In [14]: np.mean(t.repeat(10, number=1))
Out[14]: 3.8656840562820434
In [15]: t = timeit.Timer("from __main__ import t_df, np; map(np.datetime64, t_df.index.values)")
In [16]: np.mean(t.repeat(10, number=1))
Out[16]: 3.9244711160659791
```

And now for the winner:

```
In [17]: def f(s):
   ....:         return datetime(int(s[0:4]), 
   ....:                     int(s[5:7]), 
   ....:                     int(s[8:10]), 
   ....:                     int(s[11:13]), 
   ....:                     int(s[14:16]), 
   ....:                     int(s[17:19]))
   ....: t = timeit.Timer("from __main__ import t_df, f; t_df.index.map(f)")
   ....: 
In [18]: np.mean(t.repeat(10, number=1))
Out[18]: 0.33927145004272463
```

When working with `numpy`, `pandas` or `datetime`-type approaches, there definitely might be more optimizations to think of but it seems to me that staying with CPython's standard libraries and converting each date/time `str` into a tupple of `int`s and that into a `datetime` instance is the fastest way to get what you want.